# How to call a method whose name is stored in a variable

Tags: python, function-call

In the following code how to make the unicode data callable.The error that i get is `//TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable`

```
 def test(test_config):
    for i in test_config:
      print i.header //prints func1
      print type(i.header) // prints unicode
      try:
        #i.header()//TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
        func = globals()[i.header]
        print func  # found it
        func()
      except AttributeError:
        logging.error("Method  %s not implemented"%(i.header)) 

  def func1():
      print "In func1"

 test(u'func1')
```

Comment: are you attempting to call a method whose *name* is referenced by the the `i.header` variable?

Comment: What do you expect it to do when you call it?

Comment: Are you expecting `"print" ('Hello World.')` to work? If yes, it doesn't work like this in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a dict of functions that you want to call using a string:

```
def test(test_config):
    for i in test_config:
      print i.header //prints func1
      print type(i.header)
      try:
        methods[i.header]()
      except (AttributeError, TypeError):
        logging.error("Method  %s not implemented"%(i.header)) 

def func1():
    print "In func1"
def func2():
    print "In func2"

methods = {u'func1':func1, u'func2':func2} #Methods that you want to call
```

Using class:

```
class A:
    def test(self, test_config):
        try:
          getattr(self, i.header)()
        except AttributeError:
           logging.error("Method  %s not implemented"%(i.header)) 

    def func1(self):
        print "In func1"
x = A()
x.test(pass_something_here)
```

Comment: Is there any other way without using the dictionary?

Comment: +1 Explicit dict should be preferred to looking up globals(). You don't want to find someone accidentally has a header called "test".

Comment: @Rajeev Use a class then, and then you can call the methods using `getattr`.

Comment: Can u please show me the snippet

Comment: @Rajeev I've added an example.

Comment: In the class example i get a method not implemented error always why? getattr(self, i.header)()  ERROR:root:Method  func1 not implemented

Comment: @Rajeev Don't forget to cast the unicode string to a bytes string.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand, what you're trying to do is find the function whose name is referenced by the `i.header` variable, and then call it. (The title is confusing, it makes the impression you want to make the actual `unicode` instance callable).

This can be done using the `globals()`:

```
func = globals()[i.header]
print func  # found it
func()  # call it
```

Comment: If the idea is that `i.header` contains the name of a function, something like this is the best way to get it to work. But it's not the best idea - passing around function names as data is not totally safe. It would be better if you could find a different design, such as passing around the function objects directly.

Comment: func = globals()[i.header]
KeyError: u'func1'

Comment: this means the name `func1` is not defined at the point you're trying to access it. Can you please post a complete example which show how to get this error?

Comment: No i have defined func1..Please see the updated question

Comment: I'm sorry, you code is still incomplete. Please post your full example, including the call to `test` and the error message, including traceback

Comment: Please see the updated question again

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice way using a decorator

```
header_handlers = {}

def header_handler(f):
    header_handlers[f.__name__] = f
    return f

def main():
    header_name = "func1"
    header_handlers[header_name]()

@header_handler
def func1():
    print "func1"

@header_handler
def func2():
    print "func2"

@header_handler
def func3():
    print "func3"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This way it's obvious whether a function is a header handler or not